# python compound and or if condition

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

```
if tarX == 'ini' or 'txt' and act == 'm':
```

In normal English the if statement needs to verify 2 conditions are true:

1. that tarX (a variable) is either ini or txt
2. that act (a variable) is equal to m

I tried several variations to no avail. I'm sure it's my syntax/logic error not python inability.
The statement below works because (assumption) the condition to the left of the and statement compares a variable (tarX) for equality of a single string (exe) and the same holds true for the condition on the right variable (act) compared to (m). I'm assuming I'm not correctly "packaging" the if tarX == 'ini' or 'txt' and act == 'm': statement.

if tarX == 'exe' and act == 'm':

Comment: A programming language is not the same thing as normal english. Boolean logic needs to be more explicit than that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your line needs to be written like this:

```
if tarX in ('ini', 'txt') and act == 'm':
```

Remember that a programming language is *not* English, no matter how closely it resembles it.

Comment: does the in see tarX as a literal string "tarX" or in its correct context as a variable (which may have ini txt dds or exe as its value)?

Comment: @GaryWashington - It sees it as a variable.  The `in` operator in Python tests for membership.  So, the code `tarX in ('ini', 'txt')` is basically saying "can the value of the variable `tarX` be found in the tuple `('ini', 'txt')`.